# Loading page content via AJAX in JSF2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, omnifaces

I've been looking into jsf technologies lately such as [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/), [primefaces-extensions](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces-extensions/), [omnifaces](http://omnifaces.org) .

what I am not able to find is way to fetch content via ajax for example load a form, table content and put them into div or something, I've looked at `rendered` attribute, but that won't work for high scale application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A handy trick for this is using a dynamic ui:include tag like:

```
<div id="dynamicContent">
    <ui:include src="#{contentBean.content1}"/>
</div>
```

Where content1 is a string with path and .xhtml filename (usually something like /WEB-INF/content/page1.xhtml), and the parent div can be used to update.